# MongoDB read from HDFS

Tags: mongodb, hdfs

I am aware of how to set the data directory for MongoDB (using either the `--dbpath` option or changing the `dbpath` property in the conf file). But I was wondering if MongoDB can read and write data to HDFS instead of the local hard disk.

Comment: Have you reviewed the [Hapoop and MongoDB page](https://www.mongodb.com/hadoop-and-mongodb) and the guide that is available for download on that page.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere, I went through the link and the MongoDB connector for Hadoop is no longer supported. Moreover, I am looking for something like a HDFS connector for MongoDB.